# const pointer specialization produces unresolved symbol with MSVC and is fine with GCC/Clang

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, template-specialization

Please take a look at the following code:

```cpp
// header.h
#pragma once

template <typename T>
void test(T*);
```

```cpp
// lib.cpp
#include "header.h"

template <>
void test(int* const)
{
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "header.h"

int main() {
  int* ptr = nullptr;
  test(ptr);
}
```

Both gcc and clang compile and link it without any problems while MSVC ( 2015, 2019 ) produces unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl test(int *)"

note that if const keyword is removed from lib.cpp then MSVC links the code fine.

Who is right here? Is it a bug of MSVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

> **[temp.expl.spec]/6** If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

Comment: Thanks! Adding a declaration of the specialization solves the issue